# associated not save data in second table in cakephp 3.4

Tags: cakephp-3.0

In my case three table just like facilities, ports and port_facilities. first two table make relation in port_facilities table and relation is many to many.
I already insert data  facilities table and after this i try to insert data in port table and port_facilities. In port table data insert successfully but in port_facilities data not insert i try with associated but i dont know why data not insert in second table.

In port_facilities two primary key is 'port_id', 'facility_type_id'
port_id related to port and facility_type_id related to facilities table

In port Table my relation is

```
$this->hasMany('PortFacilities', [
        'foreignKey' => 'port_id',
    ]);
```

In my controller add function data format is

```
$data = [
    'port_name' => 'First Post',
    'city' => 'First Post',
    'state' => 'First Post',
    'zipcode' => 'First Post',
    'country_id' => 1,
    'phone' => 'First Post',
    'remark' => 'First Post',
    'status' => 1,
    'PortFacilities' => [
        ['port_id' => 81,
        'facility_type_id' => 2,
        'free' => 1,
        'facility_cost' => 25,
            ]
    ]
];
$port = $this->Ports->newEntity();
$port = $this->Ports->patchEntity($port, $data,['associated' => ['PortFacilities']]);
$this->Ports->save($port);
```

In ports table data successfully insert but in PortFacilities not.
Please can you explain me about this where i m messing some or wrong code.

Thanks

Comment: PortFacilities should be port_facilities

Comment: What @styks said is in reference to the data structure, not the `hasMany` or `patchEntity` calls.